# how to import the package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain in a hadoop 0.20.2 project?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, chaining

I'm trying to chain maps and reduces phases in one job. The problem is that I'm running under hadoop 0.20.2 and the package `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.Chain` seems to be deprecated and replaced by the package `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain` which is not available with the 0.20.2 version (only 0.21.0 version)

My question is: what should I do to import the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain` package to my project? Is there any patch or update to apply?